# Apache Tiles issue - org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag

Tags: struts2, apache-tiles

I tried to use tiles 2.2.2 with Struts 2. I included all the necessary jars(related to tiles, Struts2 and Struts2 tiles plugin) in the project.

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.5.8.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.jar
struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.15.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-compat-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar
xwork-core-2.3.15.jar
```

Tiles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/Welcome.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="/employee.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Employee Form" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/Employee.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="/employee.success.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Employee Added" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/SuccessEmployee.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Web.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
  <javaee:display-name>Apache Tiles framework</javaee:display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="login" 
            class="com.teg.tiles.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/welcome.tiles</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="employee" 
            class="com.teg.tiles.EmployeeAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/employee.success.tiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/employee.tiles</result>
        </action>
        <action name="employee-form">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/employee.tiles</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

When I try to run the project I got following exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag

Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Problem was DTD in tiles.xml. I changed the DTD to `<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">`
and its working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the exact same problem, the issue in my case was that JSP wasn't recompiling and Tomcat was re-using the same copy in the `work` directory. Cleaning the `work` directory and re-deploying solved the problem for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked well for us. We had the same symptoms described above after an upgrade from struts 2.3.16 to 2.3.32 and tiles from 2.0.5 to 2.2.2. Cleaning the work dir fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Tiles 2.2.2 insertAttribute
no longer accepts argument such as 'ignore="true". Remove arguments  or use insertTemplate: http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertTemplate.html